# Form validation on radio buttons Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, validation, radio-button, forms

I am trying to add validation for radio buttons on a html form in Codeigniter. The form is prepopulated with data from a database, including a list of uploaded documents (this field may be empty if the item has no associated docs). The user can upload a new document, adding it to the existing docs or adding a new doc deleting the current ones.

So I have a text field containing the org doc names and a file upload field for new:

```
 <label for="orgdocs">Documents</label>
 <input type="text" id="orgdocs" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $fetched_row['pdocs']; ?>"  />
 <input type="file" id="newdocs" name="newdocs[]" multiple="multiple" />
```

and radio buttons: (ignore the bad attempt at Spanish names)

```
 <label for="mas"><b>Añada mas</b></label>
<input type="radio" name="docsacion" style="margin-right: 0" <?php if (isset($docsacion) && $docsacion=="mas") echo "checked";?> value="mas" title="Add another document to existing docs"><br />
<label for="otra"><b>Borrar y añada otra</b></label>
<input type="radio" name="docsacion" style="margin-right: 0" <?php if (isset($docsacion) && $docsacion=="otra") echo "checked";?> value="otra" title="Remove all current docs and add new">
```

I just want to add validation. IF a new document has been selected(newdocs is not empty), dosacion is required. 
I have tried:

```
if(isset($_FILES['newdocs']['name']) && (!empty($_FILES['newdocs']['name'])))
{$this->form_validation->set_rules('docascion','Documentation upload', 'required');}
```

but this gives the error even if the newdocs field is empty and I´ve no idea why!?

Comment: try                                                                                                                      if ( !$this->upload->do_upload('newdocs',FALSE)){ //validation }

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(!empty($_FILES['newdocs']['name'])){
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('docascion','Documentation upload', 'required');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does the exact same thing. 
Logically it should work (well I think so) but it doesn´t allow submission with the Newdocs field empty and no docsacion selected??

Comment: Here is nothing which is force file field to be non-empty. This code only set validation for your `radio` button when file selected. If no file selection there then validation skipped

Comment: but even when no file is selected, the validation error appears on submission. (ie validation is not skipped)